# Tranisiton ain't working in hamburger design (css)

Tags: css

My Transition Ain't Working Can Someone Help Me I Am Trying To Do It For A Responsive Webpage

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.logo{
width: 20;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
.logo img{
    width: 25%;
    border: 3px white; 
    border-radius: 200px;
    
}

.navbar{
    display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-list {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    
}

.nav-list li{
    
list-style: none;
padding: 50px;
}

.nav-list li a{
text-decoration: none;

color: white;
}

.nav-list li a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: grey;
    }

.background{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) url(bg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-blend-mode: darken;
}

.box{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
color: peachpuff;
font-family: cursive;
max-width: 100%;
width: auto;
height: 100%;
}
.firstsection{
    height: 79vh;
}

.firsthalf{
    width: 50%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
}

.secondhalf{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 0%;
}

.text-big{
    font-size: 22px;

}

.btn{
    padding: 8px 15px;
    margin: 7px 0px;
    border: 2px solid white ;
    border-radius: 100px;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: none;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.btn:hover{
    background-color: #0066B8;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
}

.foot{
    display: flex; 
    width: 10;
    padding: 30px 0px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-blend-mode: darken;
    font-size: 25px;
    
    color: whitesmoke;
}
.burger{
    display: none;
position: absolute;
cursor: pointer;
right: 2%;
top: 19px;
}

.line{
    width: 33px;
    background-color: white;
height: 7px;
margin: 3px 3px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1140px)  {
    .nav-list{
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .navbar{
        flex-direction: column;
        position: relative;
        height: 1000px;
        transition: all 5.7 ease-out;
    }
    .burger{
        display: block;
        opacity: 100%;
    }
    .h-nav-resp{
        height: 1000px;
    }
    .vclassresp{
        opacity: 0;
        height: 0px;
        
    }
    
    
    .box{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        color: peachpuff;
        font-family: cursive;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: auto;
        height: 116%;
    }
    
 }
```

btw The Hamburger transition ain't Working For Some Reason I Need Some Help The Way It Comes Down Its Like it just comes out of nowhere

https://www.mediafire.com/file/dc7om93fjrry7fs/SG+Network.zip/file

the link above is the one that you can download

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. The minimal code to reproduce your problem, belongs directly into your question. No one here wants to go download & unpack ZIP files onto their local machine, just to be able to figure out what the problem is supposed to be.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing s (seconds) in transition duration. Add s to duration.

Change

```
transition: all 5.7 ease-out;
```

To

```
transition: all 5.7s ease-out;
```